# SQL Server error message truncated

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

This is not an error message *about* truncation. Rather, the error message itself (from SSMS) appears to have been truncated. Any idea what it was trying to tell me here? Is there a way to recover the full error message?

```
Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Line 80
The name 'SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN #actual_types.typ = 'AA' THEN #actual_types.qty ELSE 0 END) AS 'AA_Qty',
SUM(CASE WHEN #actual_types.typ = 'AB' THEN #actual_types.qty ELSE 0 END) AS 'AB_Qty',
SUM(CASE WHEN #actual_types.typ = 'AC' THEN #actual_types.qty ELSE 0 END) AS 'AC_Qty',
SUM(CASE WHEN #actual_types.typ = 'BA' THEN #actual_types.qty ELSE 0 END) AS 'BA_Qty',
SUM(CASE WHEN #actual_types.typ...
```

I'm using SSMS 2016, connected to a SQL 2000 server. For context - I was trying to create a more generic version of one of my current scripts (works fine against production data), using temp tables and sample data, to save as a reference in case I should need something similar in the future.

This was the code responsible for the error:

```
CREATE TABLE #possible_types
    (typ    varchar(2))

CREATE TABLE #actual_types
    (typ    varchar(2),
     dt     smalldatetime,
     qty    int)

INSERT  #possible_types
SELECT       'AA'
UNION SELECT 'AB'
UNION SELECT 'AC'
UNION SELECT 'BA'
UNION SELECT 'BB'
UNION SELECT 'BC'

INSERT  #actual_types
SELECT       'AA', '2015-01-01', 123
UNION SELECT 'AA', '2016-01-01', 321
UNION SELECT 'AA', '2017-01-01', 222
UNION SELECT 'BA', '2016-01-01', 777
UNION SELECT 'BC', '2017-01-01', 456

DECLARE @qry varchar(8000)
SELECT  @qry = 'SELECT' + CHAR(13)
SELECT  @qry = @qry + s.sql_gen
    FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT 'SUM(CASE WHEN #actual_types.typ = '''+ typ + ''' THEN #actual_types.qty ELSE 0 END) AS ''' + typ + '_Qty'',' + char(13) AS [sql_gen]
     FROM #possible_types) s
SELECT  @qry = LEFT(@qry, LEN(@qry) - 2) -- gets rid of last comma and carriage return
SELECT  @qry = @qry + '
                      FROM #actual_types
                      WHERE #actual_types.dt >= ''2017-01-01''
                      '
--PRINT @qry
EXEC    @qry;

DROP TABLE  #possible_types
DROP TABLE  #actual_types
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error messages in sql server are stored in sys.messages. You can query the messages table using the information provided.

```
select * from sys.messages
where message_id = 203
    and language_id = 1033 --1033 is English (assumed you can read English)
```

This returns "The name '%.*ls' is not a valid identifier."

You obviously have something else wonky in your code. Can you share your query and we can probably help determine the actual cause of the issue.

Comment: I've added the original code to the question. If I run with `PRINT` instead of `EXEC` it shows exactly what I want in the message window. I can even copy that result and paste it back into the editor and it'll execute just fine...

Comment: Note - sys.messages isn't a valid object on my (ancient) server. However `select * from master.dbo.sysmessages where error = 203 and msglangid = 1033` does work. Thanks!

Comment: Cool glad you found it on your system. Forgot you are using 2000. BTW, any chance you are able to upgrade sometime? 2000 has been out of support for close to a decade now.

Comment: Upgrading is in the plan, not sure when, but the sooner the better IMO. I came from a SQL 2014 environment into this a few weeks ago and it feels like I'm in shackles when I try to do some of the simplest things (no partitioning, only insert one row at a time, cursors everywhere, etc), not a fan!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.  Now it works for me.

I removed the ' for the name of the fields _Qty. (Actually it's not necessary for made your query working).

Moreover I  edited:

```
DECLARE @qry nvarchar(4000)
```

and

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @qry;
```

Full code edited:

```
CREATE TABLE #possible_types
    (typ    varchar(2))

CREATE TABLE #actual_types
    (typ    varchar(2),
     dt     smalldatetime,
     qty    int)

INSERT  #possible_types
SELECT       'AA'
UNION SELECT 'AB'
UNION SELECT 'AC'
UNION SELECT 'BA'
UNION SELECT 'BB'
UNION SELECT 'BC'

INSERT  #actual_types
SELECT       'AA', '2015-01-01', 123
UNION SELECT 'AA', '2016-01-01', 321
UNION SELECT 'AA', '2017-01-01', 222
UNION SELECT 'BA', '2016-01-01', 777
UNION SELECT 'BC', '2017-01-01', 456

DECLARE @qry nvarchar(4000)
SELECT  @qry = 'SELECT' + CHAR(13)
SELECT  @qry = @qry + s.sql_gen
    FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT 'SUM(CASE WHEN #actual_types.typ = '''+ typ + ''' THEN #actual_types.qty ELSE 0 END) AS ' + typ + '_Qty,' + char(13) AS [sql_gen]
     FROM #possible_types) s
SELECT  @qry = LEFT(@qry, LEN(@qry) - 2) -- gets rid of last comma and carriage return
SELECT  @qry = @qry + '
                      FROM #actual_types
                      WHERE dt >= ''2017-01-01'' 
                      '
PRINT @qry
EXECUTE sp_executesql @qry;

DROP TABLE  #possible_types
DROP TABLE  #actual_types
```

Comment: Ah, good detective work, thanks! Interesting that `EXECUTE sp_executesql @qry;` and `EXEC @qry;` do not do the same thing. Since my specific question was about the server's messages, I think @Sean gets the check mark, but definitely a +1 for this.

Comment: I agree with you.